# How to use inline property in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am writing code in HTML,I have done so much of work but I can't understand about how to place image in a row, I have use `display:inline` property but that is used in HTML5 and I'm doing code in only HTML so I can't get proper solution for that.

Please help me to sort out that problem.
I'm doing code on Notepad.

```css
.A1 {width:100%;height:500px;display:inline;}
```

```html
<div class="A1">
<h2 style="display:inline; margin-left:300px; color:#00FFE7;">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="m.png" alt="Mountain View" style="display:inline; margin-left:300px;"> 

<h2 style="display:inline; margin-left:300px;color:#00FFE7;">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="m.png" alt="Mountain View"style="display:inline;margin-left:300px;">



<h2 style="display:inline; margin-left:300px;color:#00FFE7;">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="m.png" alt="Mountain View"style="display:inline;margin-left:300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: it just demo, i want that three image in a row.

Comment: what is the expected output, can you show as image representation?

Comment: this property we used in HTML5 "display:inline;", i want same in HTML.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/vvss3j5b/1/?

Comment: Just remove the `margin-left:300px` of each `h2` tag and you will get the result.

Answer (score 2):

First I have removed all the CSS which was already added in question,
and then I have wrapped each `h2` and `img` with `div` and give that div `width:100%;` and `float:left;`. and also applied `float:left;` on `h2`   `img` tags.

```css
.A1 {

  width : 100%;
  
}

.A2 {
  float: left;
  width : 100%;
  
}

.A2 h2 {
color:#00FFE7;
  float: left;
  
}

.A2 img {
margin-left:100px;
  float: left;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="A1">
  <div class="A2">
<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="Mountain View"> 
</div>
  <div class="A2">
<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="Mountain View">
</div>

<div class="A2">
<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" alt="Mountain View">
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer is good for sure but please try to clarify what you have edited and what was the issue, don't write code only. Thanks!

Comment: First i have removed all the CSS which was already added in question and then I have wrapped each h2 and image with div and give that div 100% width and float left. and also applied float left on h2 and img tab.

Comment: Thanks! I edited your answer for you by adding your explanation to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vvss3j5b/2/)**

```
.A1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26%;
}

.inline-block h2,
.inline-block img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you.

```css
.A1Section{
  padding : 5px;
}
.A1Section .A1Img{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left : 150px;
  
}
.A1Img img{
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.A1heading{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding : 5px;
  color:#00FFE7;
}
```

```html
<div class="A1">
  <div class="A1Section">
    <h2 class="A1heading">Spectacular Mountain</h2> 
    <div class="A1Img">
      <img src="http://www.greatmountainbali.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/GMV_mountain_Frangi_ray-of-sunshine.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="A1Section">
    <h2 class="A1heading">Spectacular Mountain</h2>
    <div class="A1Img">
      <img src="http://www.greatmountainbali.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/GMV_mountain_Frangi_ray-of-sunshine.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="A1Section">
    <h2 class="A1heading">Spectacular Mountain</h2> 
    <div class="A1Img">
      <img src="http://www.greatmountainbali.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/GMV_mountain_Frangi_ray-of-sunshine.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```